# ad hoc installation just disappears on some apps no errors

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ad-hoc-distribution

I have several apps, some of them install fine as Ad Hoc, some just STOPPED installing!
I could still install them from XCode, but not Ad Hoc over the air.

No error is returned, just nothing happens. It say it wants to install the app, I touch Yes and then nothing happens.

I spent 2 days trying - revoked and re-created certificates, made sure all ids, bundle identifiers, app names etc were correct.

Connected iPad to Mac and in Xcode6.1 re-added provisioning profiles to iPad, or run it without them (it will install from app) - no effect.

NOTHING helped.

Finally, I reset iPad (Setting\General\Reset\Erase All Content and Settings)
and all apps install fine now.

Anybody had this problem? If yes, were you able to resolve it without reseting iPad?

Thanks.

iPad Air2 iOS 8.1
Xcode 6.1

Comment: Facing same issue since iOS 8 released.. Seems like Apple wants developers and testers to use their 'TestFlight'